# How to set image background from code in Android?

Tags: android

I want to set image backgroung dynamically from javacode, the image is in Drawlable folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[View.setBackground](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
int imagepath=getResourse.Getconent().getfromAssect("imagename","drawable",getPackageName());
imageview.setbackground(imagepath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int imagepath=getResourse().getcontent().getfromAssect(
                          "imagename","drawable",getPackageName());
imageview.setbackground(imagepath);
```